# Open clue tip on page load javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have used cluetip taken from this location `http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/`. I need to open the clue tip when page loads and close the cluetip on clicking the close button.

The html code:

```
    <a href="#"  class="load-local" title="Test" id="sticky" rel="#loadme">load</a>
     <div id="loadme">test content
<a href="#" class="cluetip-close">close</a>
</div>
```

Now the clue tip opens only on mouse over. I need to open the clue tip when page loads and close the cluetip on clicking the close button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your cluetips opens only mouse over, lets call this event!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.load-local').trigger('mouseover');
});
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be even better to aim for the id and use `$('#sticky').trigger(...)`, but +1 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following html and jquery

```
<div class="open">
<p>This the content show on after the page loaded.</p>
<button>close</button>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("button").click(function () {
$(".open").css("display", "none");
});
});
```

Here the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eyWvs/)